# spring social facebook renew expired token

Tags: java, facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I'm using Spring Social and Java.

When a user's facebook access_token expires is there something I can do programmatically to renew the access_token without requiring the user to log into my web application ?

My web application requires offline_access and if the access_token for a user is expired I would like to get it renewed. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a user's facebook access_token expires is there something I can do programmatically to renew the access_token without requiring the user to log into my web application ?

No.

> My web application requires offline_access

That has been deprecated for quite a while now.

> If this possible at all ?

Is doing some research of your own possible maybe?

This topic has been discussed here in all epic depth already.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/